# Azure website as a caching reverse proxy using ARR

Tags: caching, iis, azure, reverse-proxy, azure-web-app-service

We are migrating one of our websites to Azure which was previously setup using [ARR (Application Request Routing)](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) as a caching reverse proxy. It was setup as a reverse proxy which would honor the cache headers of the site it was proxying.

I've followed [this guide on using an Azure website as a reverse proxy](http://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/) and it all works fine except that it doesn't honor the cache headers of the site it is proxying. I tried adding some more pertinent elements to my `applicationHost.xdt`, but nothing I do seems to have any effect.

Here is the relevant section from my `applicationHost.xdt`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <caching xdt:Transform="Replace" enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true" maxResponseSize="1000000"></caching>

    <proxy xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" enabled="true" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="true" minResponseBuffer="4096" responseBufferLimit="12392">
        <cache enabled="true" queryStringHandling="Accept" validationInterval="00:01:00" />
    </proxy>
</system.webServer>
```

and here is my `web.config`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="CurrentTime" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^times/?(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://example.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The `web.config` just routes all requests to `/times` to `example.com`. That part is working great. It is just ignoring the cache headers of `example.com` and not caching anything which is the main use case of why we want to setup a reverse proxy.

This same configuration works just fine on a normal machine with IIS and ARR installed.

I'd really like to get this working in azure websites without having to use a web role in a cloud service. I'm hoping this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to specify the preserveHostHeader="true" flag as follows?

```
 <proxy xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" enabled="true" preserveHostHeader="true" reverseRewriteHostInResponseHeaders="true" />
```